# Font shape undefined despite using either or both of fix-cm and lmodern

Tags: fonts, warnings, latin-modern, computer-modern

My document begins:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}  % TODO 12pt
```

Nevertheless, I get errors:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OMS/cmr/m/n' in size <10> not available 
(Font)              Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' tried instead on input line 139.
```

How do I fix these?

Looking closely at the document, these are caused by something in the itemize environment (the bullet symbol?), the copyright symbol, and something in my bibliography.

Comment: It's not an error. Please, add some lines that produce the warning.

Comment: @egreg: updated the question.  Is there a way to suppress these errors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The warning is completely innocuous and is typically generated the first time an `itemize` environment is used. There are two ways to avoid it:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

or

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

I suggest to load both.

In both cases the bullet is mapped to a text glyph and LaTeX doesn't need to resort to math mode for printing it.

Note that `fix-cm` is not needed when `lmodern` is used as its works is made useless by later loading a completely different font family.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly!  (I already had fontenc, so textcomp was needed as well.)  Should I load fix-cm, or lmodern?

Comment: The choice between `fix-cm` and `lmodern` is up to your personal tastes. Computer Modern and Latin Modern fonts are very similar anyway.

Comment: @NeilG: I would recommend `lmodern`.

Comment: @mico: just out of curiosity (and perhaps this would make a good question) but why?

Comment: @NeilG: The `lmodern` package comes with a lot more glyphs than does `cmodern` (whether or not the latter is "fixed up" by loading `fix-cm` as well). The additional complement of glyphs is, admittedly, not important if you use mainly English and have little need for accented characters.